# How to mock g.message while writing unit test for grails controller

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am using grails version 1.3.7. In my application in controller, I am making use of `messages.properties` and fetching the value of the property as

```
g.message(code:messageKey, args:msgParamsArr)
```

But when I started writing unit tests for the action in the controller, it gave me errors.

Please can you help me out to understand how to mock `g.message` exactly so that the existing code will fetch the message properties from `messages.properties` only.

Comment: What errors did you get? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can mock it with:

```
controller.metaClass.message = { message ->
    message.code
}
```

You can include `message.args` too if you want to just validate the arguments with `.contains()`.

Comment: Just to say it here, in grails 2.4.3, it doesn't look like the message object is available under metaClass anymore. This solution doesn't seem to work in 2.4.3.

Answer (score -1):

This works like a champ in Grails 2.4.5:

```
controller.metaClass.message = { Map attrs -> attrs.toString() }
```